# Property Mapping Exception in Helhum upload example

Tags: typo3, extbase, fal

I am using [helhum](https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/) File Upload Demo to upload the images. But currently i got below error.

```
Exception while property mapping at property path "images.0":Property "name" was not found in target object of type "XXXX\XXXXX\Domain\Model\FileReference
```

Please help here.. How can i move forward.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Please provide more code if my answer doesn't help you

Answer (score 5):

If you followed the example extension, you are maybe missing the registration of `UploadedFileReferenceConverter` and `ObjectStorageConverter` in your `ext_localconf.php`. Took me a day to find that one:

```
ext_localconf.php
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerTypeConverter('Vendor\\EXT\\Property\\TypeConverter\\UploadedFileReferenceConverter');
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerTypeConverter('Vendor\\EXT\\Property\\TypeConverter\\ObjectStorageConverter');
```

Comment: could you please mention that how can i upload multiple images in the example of this helum? currently if i define a  multiple="multiple" then it does not work....

Answer (score 0):

In the initializeUpdateAction (or initializeCreateAction) you have to use the name of the parameter in the updateAction (or createAction) as argument.

If your updateAction looks like this:

```
public function updateAction(\Classname $yourObject)
```

You have to call the helhum function with the argument:

```
$this->setTypeConverterConfigurationForImageUpload('yourObject');
```

As a small hint for later problems: In the `setTypeConverterConfigurationForImageUpload` function you should register your own file attributes if they are not named `image` and/or `imageCollection.0` like in the example.